# About using YouTube API on TV

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

My question is related to developing HTML5 based apps for TV, using YouTube API to play videos. I've tried to find Google forum to post my question, but they recommend it here. Currently IFrame API is the recommended way. However, I would like to know the extents and proper way to use it for TV. It seems to me that embedding videos on TV will greatly limit possibilities for user. So to concrete questions:

- How to avoid "Playback on other websites has been disabled..." error? I'm not playing back from website after all. Meanwhile XBMC/Kodi can playback those videos just fine. Are they using some old deprecated API? I've tried to set `origin` var in `playerVars` to `https://www.youtube.com/tv`, but then the player object is failed to initialize.
- How the advertisements are going to be presented/interacted? So far I haven't seen anything with "Skip Ad" button using IFrame API. Only small banner image on left bottom side. But on TV there is no way to click on it. YouTube original TV app is showing "Skip Ad" type ads. Is there some special way for TV apps to present ads in proper way for devices with limited input, like TV?
- Similarly the 'i' button appearing on top right side is not useful at all on TV. How to avoid it as well?

So I would like to know the extents I can achieve in my HTML5 based app, presenting YouTube videos, comparing to native YouTube application. Both the legal way and the tricks to achieve best experience for TV users are in interest.

Comment: It is my understanding that you can't bypass the "Playback on other websites has been disabled..." error when using HTML embeds. As far as YouTube is concerned, you *are* playing the video on a website, since you embed it in an HTML app. Native apps, however, [like Android apps](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/#How_It_Works), depend on a YouTube service that is already present on the system. YouTube won't just give you access to the actual video files on their servers because they don't want you to download videos from the platform.

Comment: I could imagine though that they have an additional API which is only accessible to trusted clients (e.g. the native Android, Android TV and iOS apps) and not to the general public.